# Ordering People

Tags: combinatorics

> 1. How many ways are there to order $3$ boys and $3$ girls when the girls sit together and same for the boys.
> 2. How many ways are there to order $3$ boys and $3$ girls when $2$ boys can not sit each to other and same for the girls.

As for the first question we can look at the boys and girls as $2$ group with $3!$ ways of inner-order so it is $=2×3!=72$

As for the second question there are $3×3×2×2×1×1$ to order girl,boy,girl,... and another way when the boy is first so it is:

$2$×($3×3×2×2×1×1$)=$72$

So I get the same answer, what is the intuition behind the similarity?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I don't know what it means to say "the girls sit each to the other", and "the same gender can not sit near each other".

Comment: @MikeHaskel re-wrote those parts

Comment: "when 2 girls can not sit each to other and same for the girls" .. what? .. but i see what you meant anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Both final answers (72) are right I think. For Q1, I would write it as

$$2\times (3!)^2 = 72.$$

Reasoning: Ordering of boys gives factor $3!$. Ordering of girls gives factor $3!$. The factor of $2$ is because we can have all boys then all girls or all girls then all boys.

One way to explain the equal counts: In both cases there are $2$ choices of position for the first boy. Once that position is selected, that determines the gender of all $6$ positions. It just remains, in both cases, to sort the boys in any order and sort the girls in any order.